# Can a metric conformal to a Kahler metric be Kahler?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables, kahler-manifolds

Let $X$ be a non-compact complex manifold of dimension at least 2 equipped with a Kahler metric $\omega$. Take a smooth positive function $f : X \to \mathbb R$, and define a new hermitian metric on $X$ by $\tilde \omega = f \omega$. If $f$ is non-constant, then can this new metric ever be Kahler?

If $\dim_{\mathbb C} X = 1$ the new metric is automatically Kahler because of dimension. If $\dim_{\mathbb C} X \geq 2$ and if $X$ is compact the new metric is never Kahler. Indeed, we have that $d \tilde \omega = d f \wedge \omega$ is zero if and only if $df$ is zero by the hard Lefschetz theorem, so $f$ must be constant if $\tilde \omega$ is Kahler.

If $X$ is not compact, then to the best of my knowledge we do not have the hard Lefschetz theorem, but does the conclusion on metrics conformal to a Kahler metric still hold?

Comment: If I am not confused, it suffice to prove this that $\wedge \omega$ is injective for 1-forms. But then one just need to make a change of basis and note that $\omega$ is a positive form coming from a Kahler metric. If the wedge product vanishes, then the original Hermitian metric has to be singular, which does not make sense.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to use hard Lefschetz to conclude $df=0$ from $\omega\wedge df=0$.

This is a linear algebra fact, valid pointwise : if $\alpha \in T_x^*X$ satisfies $\omega_x \wedge \alpha=0$, then $\alpha=0$ (of course, assuming $\dim_R X \geq 4$.

The short argument is that, $\omega_x^{n-1}\wedge : T^*_x X\to \bigwedge^{2n-1} T^*_x X$ is an isomorphism ("pointwise not so hard Lefschetz", so to speak).

This said, as in Francesco's answer, you can have non proportional conformal *riemannian* metrics that are Kähler with respect to *different* complex structures, so that the corresponding 2-forms are no longer (pointwise) proportional.

Comment: Nice. Are we considering $\omega$ as a symplectic form here (instead of a metric)?

Comment: @Gunnar: definitely yes, $\omega$ is a 2-form, otherwise $d\omega$ wouldn't make much sense. The riemannian metric is $\omega(J.,.)$.

Comment: Looks like we were answering at the same time. At least I gave a slightly different explanation, so I might as well leave my answer there.

Answer (score 5):

The paper by Apostolov, Calderbank, and Gauduchon that Francesco mentions find different Kaehler structures whose associated Riemannian metrics are conformal to each other. But they correspond to different complex structures $J_+$ and $J_-$.

I believe what Gunnar is asking is whether or not one can have $f \omega$ be closed and thus Kaehler with respect to the same complex structure $J$ associated to $\omega$. The answer is no, and this has nothing at all to do with compactness or the hard Lefschetz theorem. On any almost Hermitian manifold $(M, J, \omega, g)$, it is a fact that the wedge product with the Kaehler form $\omega$ on the space of $1$-forms is injective, regardless of the compactness of $M$, the integrability of $J$, or the closedness of $\omega$. This follows, for example, from the identity

$$ \ast( \omega \wedge (\ast ( \omega \wedge \alpha) ) = - (m-1) \alpha $$

where $\alpha$ is any $1$-form on $M$, where $\ast$ is the Hodge star operator, and the real dimension of $M$ is $2m$. (One sees that the only requirement is that $m>1$.)

Answer (score 2):

There are examples in real dimension $4$ of manifolds having two conformally equivalent
Kahler metrics, inducing the same conformal structure but with opposite orientation.

See the paper [Ambikahler geometry, ambitoric surfaces and Einstein 4-orbifolds](http://www.cirget.uqam.ca/~apostolo/papers/ambitoric.pdf) by Apostolov, Calderbank and Gauduchon.

Comment: Thanks Francesco, that's an interesting article. However it does seem to answer a slightly different question. In the notation of the article, we have a fixed complex structure $J$ on $M$ (such that $X = (M,J)$) and ask for structures $(g_1,J,\omega_1)$ and $(g_2, J, \omega_2)$ such that: $g_2 = f^2 g_1$, and ask if the second structure can be Kahler if the first one is and if $f$ is non-constant. In particular, if this is possible, then both structures would induce the same orientation on $M$.

Comment: Ah ok, I did not notice that your complex structure $J$ was *fixed*. At any rate, I hope you can find this paper useful :-)  