# Plurisubharmonic function and complete Kähler metric on certain Kähler manifold

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, dg.differential-geometry, cv.complex-variables, complex-geometry

Given a compact Kähler manifold $M$, let $D$ be an effective divisor on $M$.

1. Is $M\setminus D$ pseudoconvex? That is, can we find a smooth plurisubharmonic function that exhausts $M\setminus D$ ?
2. Can we find a complete Kähler metric on $M\setminus D$ ?

If $1$ and $2$ are not true, can we find any obstructions? Or necessary and sufficient conditions?

**Note:** if $D$ is an ample divisor, we can choose an Hermitian metric on $[D]$ which is the associated divisor bundle to $D$, then we can take $-ln|s_{D}|^{2}_{h}$ to be the strongly smooth exhaust plurisubharmonic function on $M\setminus D$. Surely, this is just a Stein (or Affine) manifold. Given such a plurisubharmonic function on $M\setminus D$ we can easily contruct a compelte Kähler metric.

Comment: If D is smooth (or merely snc, which you can restrict to thanks to Hironaka), you can take for 2. a metric of the form $\omega+dd^c(-\log(-\log |s|_h^2))$ for $\omega$ a background Kähler form on $X$. The resulting metric has Poincaré growth in the direction(s) transverse to the divisor.

Comment: For part 2 of your question see my answer and my comments here https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239677/does-a-k%C3%A4hler-manifold-always-admit-a-complete-k%C3%A4hler-metric/271277#comment708770_271277

Comment: If you mean $M\setminus D$ is strongly pseudoconvex domain? then such variety must admit complete Kahler Einstein metric due to Cheng-Yau and see Tsuji paper also https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.4038.pdf which such $X\setminus D$ does not admit Kahler-Einstein metric in general, so it can not be  strongly pseudoconvex domain in general.

Comment: If $M$ is compact and $D\subset M$ is compact and has complex $\text{codim}\geq  2$, then $M\setminus D$ is not Stein, hence it cannot be strongly pseudoconvex domain

Comment: Moreover about your first part of your question: An strong result of Griffiths show that a domain $\Omega\subset \mathbb C^n$which admits a complete Hermitian metric with non-positive holomorphic sectional curvature is pseudoconvex. https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01418742 and also see Shiffman paper https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01350128

Comment: Assume $M$ is a Stein manifold and $ D ⊂ M$ is a closed subset. If $M \setminus D$
locally admits complete Kahler metrics induced by bounded plurisubharmonic functions, then there exists a complete Kahler metric on $M \setminus D$ induced by a globally defined plurisubharmonic
function on $M$ see Proposition 2.1. of https://arxiv.org/pdf/1505.06451.pdf

Comment: Moreover, Yau and Mok showed that a bounded domain which admits a complete Hermitian metric satisfying $−c≤\text{Ricci curvature} ≤0$ must be pseudoconvex. Which is parallel to result of Shiffman and Griffiths but in Ricci curvature setting instead sectional curvature setting see https://books.google.fr/books?id=9S4ECAAAQBAJ&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Also, by using embedding theorem of Bishop-Narasimhan, there exists a complete Kahler metric on $X-V$ , (by using Grauert construction of complete Kahler metric on $\mathbb C^n-\{0\}$)where $X$ is Stein manifold and $V$ is closed analytic subvariety of any dimension.I learnt it from the paper of Yau-Mok

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Question 1: Plurisubharmonic functions extend across codimension 2 subvarieties . Let X be the complex projective plane blown up at one point and D be the exceptional divisor then any plurisubharmonic function on the complement of D in X extends to X and is therefore a constant.

Comment: Hi, Mohan, this is a really nice answer. I would appreciate it if you can provide me the proof for the fact that plurisubharmonic functions extend across codimension 2 singularities. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you. See Grauert Remmert Mathematische Zeitschrift vol 65 page 175-194 or Noguchi and Ochiai 's book Geometric Function Theory of Several Complex Variables page 136 . The idea of the proof is to show that psh functions locally bounded above extend past pluripolar sets and then show psh function are locally bounded above in case of codimension 2 singularities

Answer (score 1):

For 1 it is not always the case.

It is well-known, that critical points of a plurisubharmonic Morse function on a complex manifold $X$ have Morse index $\le \dim_\mathbb C X$. Hence, if $X=M\backslash D$ admits a plurisubharmonic exhaustion, its homology vanishes in dimensions $>\dim_\mathbb CM$.

At the same time it is easy to come up with with a pair $(M, D)$ such that $\dim_\mathbb C M=2$ while $H^3(M\backslash D)\neq 0$:

For example, take $M={\rm Bl}_p T^4$ to be a blow-up of a torus in a point and let $D$ be the exceptional divisor. Then $M\backslash D=T^4\backslash p$.

Comment: Hi, Yury, thanks for ur answer. But what about the case when the plurisubharmonic function is not Morse?

Comment: If $f$ is a psh exhaustion of $X$, then for an appropriately small (and decaying at infinity) function $g$ the sum $f+g$ is also psh. If you choose $g$ generic enough, the sum $f+g$ should be Morse.

Comment: Hi, Yury, I am sorry but I do not get it. By being plurisubharmonic, I mean the complex hessian of the function is nonnegative definite which is a closed condition. So I do not see why the perturbation works here.

Comment: Sorry, my bad, i had in mind strongly psh functions, like for Stein manifolds. Well, it might be more subtle in this case, but still i believe that 1 does not hold.