# Is there a complete Kahler metric on a bounded domain？

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, cv.complex-variables

Let $\Omega\subset\mathbb{C}^n$ be a bounded domain.
By the theorems of Cheng-Yau and Mok-Yau, $\Omega$ admits a complete Kahler-Einstein metric if and only if $\Omega$ is a pseudoconvex domain.

My question:
Does every bounded domain admit a complete Kahler metric? If not, what is the condition to ensure the existence of such complete Kahler metric?

Comment: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/239677/does-a-k%C3%A4hler-manifold-always-admit-a-complete-k%C3%A4hler-metric

Answer (score 2):

If the domain is Reinhardt, then it has to be logarithmaically convex.
A general result may be found in Math. Ann. 257, 191 (1981).