# Does every group arise as the fundamental group of a complete Kähler manifold?

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, complex-geometry, riemannian-geometry, kahler-manifolds

The fundamental group of a manifold is countable, and every countable group $G$ arises as the fundamental group of a (smooth) manifold; see [this comment](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/192230/is-there-a-manifold-with-fundamental-group-mathbbq#comment479763_192230) or [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1362689/39599) for a construction of an open subset $U \subset \mathbb{R}^5$ with $\pi_1(U) \cong G$.

Note that every smooth manifold admits a complete Riemannian metric. In fact, every conformal class contains a complete metric, see *The Existence of Complete Riemannian metrics* by Nomizu and Ozeki. Therefore, **every countable group arises as the fundamental group of a complete Riemannian manifold**.

As the hermitian property is preserved under conformal change, every conformal class of a hermitian metric on a complex manifold contains a complete hermitian metric. Replacing $U$ with $V := U\times\mathbb{R} \subset \mathbb{R}^6 = \mathbb{C}^3$, we see that **every countable group arises as the fundamental group of a complete hermitian manifold**.

Note that $V$ also admits a Kähler metric. However, unlike the hermitian case, the Kähler property is not preserved under non-constant conformal change, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/69792/21564). In fact, not every Kähler manifold admits a complete Kähler metric, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/239677/21564). Despite this, do we still have the Kähler analogue of the two bold statements above?

> Does every countable group arise as the fundamental group of a complete Kähler manifold?

It's worth pointing out that the question of which groups arise as the fundamental groups of *compact* Kähler manifolds (which are necessarily complete) is an active area of research. Such groups are known as Kähler groups and much is known about them, see [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/q/270023/21564).

Comment: Isn't it true that every fundamental group of a Kaeler manifold has even first Betti number?

Comment: Only true for compact Kaehler manifolds

Comment: Sorry, missed the absence of "compact".

Comment: Finite volume + complete is probably the right condition in this context.

Comment: Compactness is essential for evenness of odd betti numbers. The Riemann sphere minus two point has a complete Kahler metric of finite volume.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Any Stein manifold admits a complete Kähler metric. Start with a connected real analytic manifold with the given fundamental group. A  suitable tubular neighbourhood of the complexification will be Stein. This Stein manifold will have the same fundamental group as the original manifold. For details see page 383 of *Narasimhan, R.*, [**On the homology groups of Stein spaces**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01428900), Invent. Math. 2, 377-385 (1967). [ZBL0148.32202](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0148.32202).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Just for my own edification, let me record the following. The lemma you reference shows that if $U \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ is open, then there is a Runge domain $D \subset \mathbb{C}^n$ which deformation retracts onto $U$. A Runge domain is an open set which is holomorphically convex, so any such set in $\mathbb{C}^n$ is Stein (it is holomorphically separable due to the coordinate functions $z_i$).

Comment: Do you have a reference for the existence of a complete Kähler metric on a Stein manifold?

Comment: @MichaelAlbanese Because they all admit proper holomorphic embeddings in $C^n$ you can pull back the metric.

Comment: @MoisheKohan: Of course. Thanks.

Comment: You can take the Levi form of the square of a positive strictly plurisubharmonic exhaustion function as your complete Kahler metric. The exhaustion function is Lipschitz wrt this metric which proves completeness.